# Is there a quick way to see which WB questions are on the HNQ roster?

Tags: support

These are the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) that gets displayed across the entire set of Stacks:

[image: HNQ]

A different group of questions seem to get placed on it on refresh. While clearly these are the ones with lots of traffic and votes, and there's a formula for it somewhere, I have no way of knowing which WB questions if any are currently on HNQ.

**Does anyone know any way to find out?**

Comment: Over at Mi Yodeya, I'm [trying](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34456/reshet-cham-test) to hack together a way to make our questions that show up on the HNQ list get posted to our chat room. So far, I haven't come up with anything that's reliable, fast, or elegant. The best attempts I've got right now (still being tested) are based on http://createfeed.fivefilters.org/. I'll report back (and to MSE) when we settle on something.

Answer (score 4):

I only know a manual way. You click on the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) link (also included in the image), and manually count on the two pages. If there's any way more fancy, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's an API to at least get a list of all hot questions, but don't know for sure.